# Launch a Windows program from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

I know this has been answered a couple of times before, but that didn't work for me.

My Code is:

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec("C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe");
```

When I start the JS file with NodeJS it doesn't do anything.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape your backslashes and quote the path because it contains a space:

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec('"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"');
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. Can the reason it doesn't work be that my JS file is placed in F:\\ and not C:\\?

Comment: It worked for me (I tested with calc.exe), although it now seems that it's actually a space issue for you. The path needs to be quoted because of the space in "Program Files." I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too old,may be useful for someone

it opens windows calculator(calc.exe)

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.exec('start calc.exe', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    process.exit(0);// exit process once it is opened
})
```